# What to use as a delimiter so I can detect the original inputs. Any good ideas. Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an Encoder (using `openssl`) that can encrypt and decrypt strings like so:

```
new_addresses
=> ["fasfds", "someaddress", "123- this is also a valid address"]
[8] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> Encoder.encrypt(new_addresses.join(' '))
=> "55C2FB253468204EA9D3F5CE6D58DC4088BD52731B90B9C0C8EB5FE7FA1CD4E7B41F0A84DC46C69E09A10DC1931C6A976A58E29C"
[9] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> enc=_
=> "55C2FB253468204EA9D3F5CE6D58DC4088BD52731B90B9C0C8EB5FE7FA1CD4E7B41F0A84DC46C69E09A10DC1931C6A976A58E29C"
[10] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> Encoder.decrypt(enc)
=> "fasfds someaddress 123- this is also a valid address"
```

The issue I have here is that I have no idea which were the original 3 addresses. The `new_addresses` which are merely params that come in from a form are an array separated by commas. But when I join them together and encode it, I lose the comma delimiter and the array structure when I decrypt it so I have no idea what were the original 3 `addresses`. Any ideas on what I can do so that after I decrypt the string, I still can detect on what the original 3 addresses are.

These are valid characters in an address:

```
' '
-
_
^
%
$
#
...
```

really any characters.

Comment: You could use a vertical pipe (|) or tilde (~), as they are unlikely to appear in the content of your field inputs.

Comment: good suggestion!

Comment: to be sure your character of choice is never in the content submitted, i'd recommend front end validation to check for it/prohibit it too.

Comment: @AnsonWHan,  *is never in the content submitted* -- Really? You can do that?  If so, you wouldn't need backend validation at all.

Comment: @AnsonWHan, If you are going to suggest an ascii character, why not NUL, i.e. `\x00`?

Comment: I'm suggesting form validation on both front and backend for the character of choice, to indicate a character isn't allowed. I didn't recommend NULL as some address forms (second line of street address) could in fact be null.

Comment: @AnsonWHan, You seem to be confusing the js value `null` and the ascii character `\x00`, which is named NUL.  A ruby program can *never* receive the js value `null`.

Comment: @Jwan622, what encryption are you using? What is an `Encoder`?

Comment: @7stud "Null character" and "NUL" mean the same thing, the later is just the ASCII standard abbreviation. See also: "Bell character" as "BEL and "Escape character" as "ESC" There's no need to get overly technical here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your encryption algorithm uses only the characters 0-9 and A-Z.  In that case, you can use any character that is not one of those characters to `join()` your encrypted strings together, for instance `"-"`:

```
encrypted_str = "55C2FB253-3F5CE6D58DC4-B5FE7FA1CD4E7"
encyrpted_pieces = encrypted_str.split '-'

decrypted_pieces = encrypted_pieces.map do |piece|
  Encoder.decrypt piece
end
```

On the other hand, if you want to join your strings together first, then encrypt the combined string, you can use the non printing ascii character named NUL to glue the pieces together.  NUL's ascii code is 0, which can be represented by the hex escape `\x00` inside a String:

```
decrypted_str = "fasfds\x00someaddress\x00123- this is also a valid address"
puts decrypted_str
pieces = decrypted_str.split "\x00"
p pieces

--output:--
fasfdssomeaddress123- this is also a valid address
["fasfds", "someaddress", "123- this is also a valid address"]
```

Magic.

Of course, the separator character should be a character that won't appear in the input.  If the input can be binary data, e.g. an image, then you can't use `\x00` as the separator.

> These are valid characters in an address:
>
> ```
> ' '
> -
> _
> ^
> %
> $
> #
> ...
> ```

Note that you didn't list a comma, which would be an obvious choice for the separator.